# XAML ListView auto width column

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm trying to develop an universal app for personal use, however I am running into the problem that the second column in my ListView doesn't align properly, I have the following XAML:

```
<ListView 
        Grid.Row="1"

        ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{StaticResource HighAlchImage}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Which results in the following image:
[image]

However, I want the second image (the one that's the same every time) to align with itself, preferably with the width of the first Column to be Auto. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You need to stretch width of the ListViewItem to the width of the ListView.

i.e. You have to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the ListView's `ItemContainerStyle` to `Stretch`.

Normally I would create a copy of the Default ListViewItemStyle, then do my customization based on the default style:

(put the following code inside `<ListView>` Tag)

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <!-- Better to put this to another XAML file -->
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyleDefault" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckMode="Inline" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyleStretch" TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleDefault}">
        <!-- Magic here -->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="ListViewItemStyleStretch"/>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- Your ItemTemplate... -->
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Ryan. `HorizontalContentAlignment` set on `Stretch` was all I needed

Answer (score 1):

The `Grid` panel has such functionality built in. In order to utilize it you should set `SharedSizeGroup` on your column definitions, and then set attached `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` on the element parenting all grids which should share column sizes (`ListView` would be a good choice in your case).

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{StaticResource HighAlchImage}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You might want to take some care while choosing values for `SharedSizeGroup` properties - preferably, they should be unique per visual tree.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Windows store apps? (Did mention universal app in original post)

Comment: @CaptainSensible Why the downvote? I never implied that this works for _UWP_. The question is tagged with _WPF_ and not with _UWP_, and it does work for _WPF_.

Comment: The question starts as follows: "I'm trying to develop an universal app ...". The intent to develop a UWP app instead of a WPF app has been repeated in the comment to your response. The tag is therefore wrong and I have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the opposite:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This way your first column will use the space it needs and the second column will be aligned.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to create practically the same result. Except now the text is always fully visible, regardless of resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a solution,  I  ended up here, @Ryan answer is near to solve my problem, but some adjusts must be done.

1 Create An style:

```
<Style x:Key="LstViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

2 Apply style to the list view as this:

```
<ListView
    ...
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LstViewItemContainerStyle}">
</ListView>
```